# A list of dataframes in R, and I have to make three sub-dataframes with each df element

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a set of csv files, 64 of them. all of those title are named like "LineNum_nnn.csv" (LineNum_101.csv, LineNum_107.csv, LineNum_501.csv, ...)
Each csv file has five columns:

Date / On / Off / Transfer / LineNum

2020-01-02 / 8874 / 7170 / 1886 / 211

2020-01-03 / 8928 / 7170 / 1886 / 211

... so on. All of them have about 800 rows.

I used lapply function to do two things:

1.import all the csv files in my working directory and 2.apply my pre-processing function(named function_merged) to all 67 dataframes in the list.

I imported csv files with this code. Works well.

```
wholeDataList = lapply(fileList, function(x) read.csv(x, encoding = "UTF-8"))

head(wholeDataList[[2]], 3)
A data.frame: 3 × 5
Date    On  Off Transfer    LineNum
<chr>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
1   2020-01-02  16830   14564   4536    102
2   2020-01-03  17440   14978   4614    102
3   2020-01-04  12579   10862   3011    102
```

applied my pre-processing function(function-Merged) to the dataframe list:

```
wholeDataList_merged = lapply(wholeDataList, function(x) function_Merged(x))
```

Also works well. Now I have a one-dimensional list with 67 processed dataframes in a row. for example:

```
head(wholeDataList_merged[[2]], 3)
```

gives me

```
A data.frame: 3 × 11
Date    On  Off Transfer    LineNum Days    Workdays    On_RunMed   NumericDate Loess_Fit   Loess_SE
<date>  <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <chr>   <fct>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   2020-01-02  16830   14564   4536    102 Thu TRUE    16709   18263   16628.28    261.7660
6   2020-01-07  15734   13311   4268    102 Tue TRUE    16709   18268   16919.24    187.8690
7   2020-01-08  16709   14375   4698    102 Wed TRUE    16830   18269   16960.49    175.9965
```

Then the major problem: as you can see these dataframes have a **Date** column, and I have to **split all those 67 dataframes, each into three frames based on their dates**: 2010-08-09 / 2020-11-17 / 2021-07-04.

for example, that "wholeDataList_merged[[2]]" (dataframe of line number 102. right above one) has to be **trimmed into three dataframes with their date information**:
I want Line102_Phase1(before 20-08-09), Line102_Phase2(btw 20-08-09 and 20-11-17), Line102_Phase3(btw 20/11/17 and 21/07/04).
... for all those 67 dataframes. (sigh)

I know R function cannot make multiple outputs. so I hope I can do this(splitting a dataframe into three sub-frames based on date value)

like,

```
        function_name <- function(dataframe) {
            temp_list <- list[]
        
            df_Phase1 <- 
            dataframe["2020-02-18" <= dataframe$Date
            & dataframe$Date <= "2020-08-09",]
            temp_list <- append(temp_list, df_Phase1)
        
            df_Phase2 <- 
            dataframe["2020-08-10" <= dataframe$Date
            & dataframe$Date <= "2020-11-17",]
            temp_list <- append(temp_list, df_Phase2)
        
            df_Phase3 <- 
            dataframe["2020-11-18" <= dataframe$Date
            & dataframe$Date <= "2021-07-04",]
            temp_list <- append(temp_list, df_Phase3)
        
            return(temp_list)
    #and attatch those three splitted frames right next to the original dataframe(then it would be 67*4),

# or make a new 67*3 list with those splitted frames... whatever.
        }
```

And most af all, these **splitted dataframes have to contain 1. their line numbers(102, 104, ..) and 2. each phases(1, 2, 3) in the dataframe variable name.** for example "Line104_Phase2".

How can I do this? Well do I have to unlist those frames and extract three of them by date from each dataframes with for loops and dynamic variables?

splitting... I think it could be done with lots of effort somehow, but I cannot even grasp anything with the variable names. Help me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. There is a lot of text, some of it seems irrelevant (like your initial attempts to read a set of CSV files). Can you provide a *minimal* example in the form of sample data, a clear problem statement and your expected output based on the minimal sample data. That will help us understand what you want to do. I feel like `split` is going to be your friend here but I'm not sure what you're really asking and what you're expected output is supposed to look like.

Comment: Thanks! uh... can you understand now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a reproducible examples, here are some data that hopefully replicate your problem.

```
set.seed(42)
dateIntervals<-as.Date(c("2010-08-09", "2020-11-17", "2021-07-04"))
possibleDates<-seq(dateIntervals[1]-1000, dateIntervals[3], by = "day")
genDF<-function() data.frame(Date = sample(possibleDates, 100), Value = runif(100))
listdf<-replicate(2, genDF(), simplify = FALSE)
```

Now `listdf`, which should play the role of your `wholeDataList_merged`, has only two elements and each element just two columns, but it shouldn't make any difference. Next, you can try:

```
lapply(listdf, function(x) split(x, findInterval(x$Date, dateIntervals)))
```

And you will see each element being split into three elements depending on the date.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it tomorrow! Uh... i have a question why do i have to set a seed?

Comment: You don't have. It's just to have a repro example, since I'm generating random data. You just have to check whether the last line works for your list.